# React doesn't render second nested element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use react nested elements here, but am I unable to render the third element. The first two react sub-elements work perfectly but the second nested element doesn't render? Why is that so? How should I fix this?

```
var Nested=React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        return(
           <div className="second">nested div</div>
          )
      }     
  });

  var Component=React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        return(

            <div className={this.props.className}>
            <Nested>
              <Nested/> //this doesn't want to render
            </Nested>
            <Nested/>
            </div>

            );
      }
   });
   ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
     <Component/>
   </div>,
   document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a custom component to render nested components or elements, using **{this.props.children}** in your custom component's render method will allow you to do that.